# SQL: Convert integer into formatted hex string

Tags: sql, postgresql

In PostgreSQL, let's say I have the following table:

```
+-------+---------+
|       | someVal |
| myInt |         |
+-------+---------+
| 123   | a       |
+-------+---------+
| 456   | b       |
+-------+---------+
| 789   | c       |
+-------+---------+
```

I want to convert the myInt column into a formatted string that contains the hex representation of the integer in it and rename the column. So it would look something like the following:

```
+----------+---------+
|          | someVal |
| myHex    |         |
+----------+---------+
| hex: 7B  | a       |
+----------+---------+
| hex: 1C8 | b       |
+----------+---------+
| hex: 315 | c       |
+----------+---------+
```

What would the query look like to convert the integer?

Comment: Please show us what you tried and where you got stuck.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try the following in PostgreSQL.

```
select
   concat('hex: ', cast(to_hex(ms) as text)) as myHex,
   someVal
from yourTable
```

Comment: I want it to be a string with that hex interpolated inside of it.